# AS3: Differentiate between Static and Dynamic TextField

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textfield

I'm trying to iterate through all the display objects on the stage and retrieve data from only the dynamic and input Textfields.

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < this.numChildren; i++){
            var o = getChildAt(i);
            if(o is TextField) {
                if (o.type==TextFieldType.INPUT || (o.type == TextFieldType.DYNAMIC)) { 
                    trace(o.name);
                }
            }
        }
```

However what the if statement for detecting the textfields type accepts static text aswell. Im scratching my head as to why this is, any help?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
  if(o is StaticText){
     //trace(o);  // [object StaticText]
  }
```

Read more about [`StaticText`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StaticText.html).

Comment: Yeah what I've done is

    `if(o is StaticText){
      trace("Skipping " + o.name);
    } else{
        trace("Not skipping " + o.name)
    }`

And I have all three different types of textfields (Dynamic, Input and Static) and the iteration does not yield true for any of them

Comment: @KevinLerdwichagul take a look at docs , `StaticText` has no `name` attribute , it has only `text`: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StaticText.html#text

Comment: My bad, was just giving a comment off the top of my head, 

regaurdless, the point was even if I had put in trace("Static text found") the if statement still does not return true and the trace method is not triggered even when there clearly is a Static textField in the DisplayList